# Newsletter form embedded into second model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a very simple Newsletter sign up that I can use across my app.

I have created a newsletter model which just collects an email address. I haven't created a seperate controller for newsletter as I was under the impression I can define everything I need to in my Jobs controller.

The issue I am having is that I want to display the Newsletter sign up form on my `jobs#index` page (which obviously uses my jobs controller).

What I can't work out is how I can define both new and create for my Newsletter within my Jobs controller?

Ideally I would like my form to sit in a partial that I can then render onto my Job pages and that looks something like this:

```
 <%= Form_for @newsletter do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

 <% end %>
```

It would be great if someone could advise me on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with custom actions such as new_newsletter and create_newsletter inside your jobs controller, that being said you are much better off creating a newsletter controller with create action and after creation just do a redirect back. This way it will be easier to have a partial and you can call it from other parts of the app, not just jobs